# Problem pushing char* to vector, but after each iteration its adding a pointer to the same values buffer into the vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, char

[SOLVED] I changed the char variables to a `std::string` array, where I push float variables to the array. After all this you can convert the `std::string` to a `const char*`

I'm making client to a server. And I want to send data to the server, but when I run this code I am getting 4.5 twice instead of 180 & 4.5. I am using chars, because the send function that I am using only supports chars.

Emptying the char (doesn't work)
Printed the value before the if statement ends (This shows that the value is correct), but when the for loop loops the second time it is 4.5 instead of 180.

```
float an = 180;
float dis = 4.5;

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    set.measurements.push_back(an); 
    set.measurements.push_back(dis);
}

for (int i = 0; i < set.measurements.size(); i++){
    sprintf(values, "%0.1f", set.measurements[i]);
    if (i == 1 && i != 0){
         std::cout << "{ 4.5 }" << '\n'; // expected output
         char *dist = new char[10];
         dist = values; // <-- Value is 4.5
         meas.push_back(dist); 
         // This is 4.5 but the angle doesn't stay 180
         delete dist;
    }
    if (i == 0 && i != 1){
        std::cout << "{ 180 }" << '\n'; // Expected output
        char *ang = new char[10];
        ang = values; // <-- Value is 180 here
        meas.push_back(ang); 
        delete ang;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  std::cout << &*meas[0] << '\n';
}
```

I expect the output to be 180 & 4.5, but the actual output is 4.5 & 4.5

Comment: You're going to need to present the [mcve] you've been debugging with.

Comment: `ang = values;` just causes you to leak that `new` allocated memory, and then you are trying to delete `values` instead. *After* you pushed back the pointer to it, that is (but without seeing the rest of the code, who knows what `meas` is and what it does with the pointer anyway).

Comment: `if (i == 1 && i != 0)` What's the point in having both conditions?

Comment: TL;DR: Do not use `new` and `delete` in C++.  Your code is full of undefined behavior. If you need to allocate objects on the heap, use `std::shared_ptr`. Also, use `std::string` instead of `char*`. If you need it as a `char*`, it has a `c_str()` member function.

Comment: There is no point in having both conditions, it was just one of the many (stupid) tests  i did to look if i did something wrong.

Comment: Well, your biggest mistake is deleting dist over and over again cause your new allocation right before vanishes

Comment: @Blaze Meas is just an empty vector, but i will try your answer and Nikos

Comment: @NikosC. I didn't know about the c_str function

Comment: you should include your whole code. the allocation of `values` is still missing. And if `values` is a vector `sprintf(values,` is going to do some crazy stuff.

Comment: May I recommend you [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for learning C++? Coding by guessing may work for some languages, but is terrible way to learn C++, and it will bite you at every other line.

Comment: @mHvNG what kind of vector? If it's a vector of `char*` then it's a problem if you just `delete` that memory afterwards. If it's a vector of `std::string` then that's one issue less because an `std::string` will be constructed with a copy of the string that the `char*` represents. This is why you should post your whole code (or rather a minimal reproducible example), not just a snippet.

Comment: A Tour of C++ (Bjarne Stroustrup) seems like a great fit for you @mHvNG.

Comment: @TarickWelling I never said values is a vector, i said Meas is a vector. Values is an empty char[] and in the sprintf function I am pushing the 180 and 4.5 values to it.

Comment: first point still stands, you should include a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  which we can compile ourselves without guessing how some variables are declared

Comment: @TarickWelling i edited my code with everything you need.

Comment: @TarickWelling Its not a secret that I am not the best at C++. But i am trying to learn  what my problem is, and learn from it for the next time

Comment: My recommendation for 'A Tour of C++ (Bjarne Stroustrup)' is a genuine recommendation. It is available online, fairly cheap, created by the creator of C++ and has a great writing style for learning all the needed details. If you really want the best version you should take the newest edition: 2. It is also great for new informatics students with some programming experience.

Comment: @TarickWelling Thanks for the tip, its more the fact that I am maybe not that fairly new to C++. But this is the first time going a bit deeper into C++. But i will have a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *dist = new char[10];
```

This allocates a new `char` array, and sets `dist` to point to it.

```
dist = values; // <-- Value is 4.5
```

The next line immediately replaces the `dist`pointer to the `new`-ed buffer, leaking this memory. This now sets `dist` to point to some other buffer (presumably), instead.

```
meas.push_back(dist);
```

This now adds the pointer to the `values` object into the vector. Each iteration of the loop, therefore, ends up adding a pointer to the same `values` buffer into the vector, and that's what you're seeing, in the end.

```
delete dist;
```

This is still pointing to `values`. From the context, it is unlikely that `values` was originally created with `new`, and even if it was, each iteration of the loop will end up `delete`ing the same pointer. Either way, this is undefined behavior, and with enough looping, your entire program will likely crash.

The second `if` statement repeats all of the above bugs.

Since your intent is, apparently, to write C++ code, you should actually use the C++ library, namely the formatted output operators, and `std::string`s, that will correctly allocate and manage all the memory for you, eliminating these kinds of common, logical bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The reason I used char was because I am using it in a function where it needed a char, but as someone said as a comment there is a c_str function.

Comment: Please remember that `c_str()` returns a `const CharT*` (`const char*`) and can't be used for writing to the `std::string`